# wrong current page on codeigniter pagination for ajax content

Tags: ajax, codeigniter, pagination

Content on one of my page is fetched through Ajax. Content and pagination are all processed and loaded into container div pretty well except for the challenge of wrong placement of CURRENT PAGE on the pagination.

1st page is always set as current page and I cant seem to figure out why

URL sample for e.g 2nd page:

```
http://localhost/mysite/index.php/category/item/2
```

Pagination method being called by Ajax:

Method is passed two POST param cat_id for content to fetched from DB and current page number

```
public function category_product_pagination(){  

    if(!empty($this->input->post('cat_id')) && !empty($this->input->post('page'))){

        $cat_id_enc     =   $this->input->post('cat_id');
        $cat_id         =   $this->decryptGetId($cat_id_enc);

        $page       =   $this->input->post('page');

        $slug   = $this->ajax_model->dbSingleColQuery('slug', 'product_category', "id = '".$cat_id."'");                

        /////////////// PAGINATION //////////////
        $config = array();
        $config["base_url"] = base_url() . "/category/".$slug;      
        $total_row = $this->ajax_model->dbRowCountQuery('product', "cat_id = '".$cat_id."' AND del_status = 0");
        $config["total_rows"] = $total_row;
        $config["per_page"] = $this->per_page;
        $config['use_page_numbers'] = TRUE;
        $config['num_links'] = 2;
        $config['next_link'] = 'Next';
        $config['prev_link'] = 'Previous';
        $config['uri_segment'] = 3;

        $config['first_tag_open']       = '<li>';
        $config['first_tag_close']      = '</li>';
        $config['last_tag_open']        = '<li>';
        $config['last_tag_close']       = '</li>';
        $config['prev_tag_open']        = '<li>';
        $config['prev_tag_close']       = '</li>';
        $config['next_tag_open']        = '<li>';
        $config['next_tag_close']       = '</li>';
        $config['cur_tag_open']         = '<li><a class="current">';
        $config['cur_tag_close']        = '</a></li>';

        $config['num_tag_open']         = '<li>';
        $config['num_tag_close']        = '</li>'; 

        $this->pagination->initialize($config);

        $limit_row = ($page == 1) ? 0: ($page - 1) * $config["per_page"];
        $product_list   = $this->ajax_model->dbMultiRowQuery('*', 'product', "cat_id = '".$cat_id."' AND del_status = 0", 'id', 'DESC', $limit_row, $config["per_page"]);

        $str_links = $this->pagination->create_links();
        $pagination = explode('&nbsp;',$str_links);

        /////////////// PAGINATION //////////////

        echo '<ul class="tsc_pagination">'; 
        foreach ($pagination as $key => $link) {
            echo $link;
        }
        echo '</ul>';

    }

}// End function
```

Ajax/Jquery

```
(function($){       

    var cat_id          = $("#filter_form_id input[name=cat_id]").val();

    var form_data = {
        cat_id : cat_id,
        page : page,
        secure_csrf_token_name : csrf
    }

    $("#this_category_product_container").html('<img src="'+base_url+'assets/img/ajax-loader.gif" />');

    $.ajax({
        url :   site_url+"/category-product-loader",
        type :  "POST",
        data :  form_data,
        dataType: "html",
        cache :     false
    })
    .done(function(resp){           
        if(resp == 5){                      
            $("#this_category_product_container").html(respMsg('No product match found!', 2));      
        }
        else{
            $("#this_category_product_container").html(resp);   // Product Loading into container tag

            // Generate Pagination
            $.ajax({
                    url:        site_url+'/category-product-pagination',
                    type :      "POST",
                    cache:      false,
                    dataType:   "html",
                    data :  form_data,
                    success:    function(paginate){
                        //alert(page);
                                    $("#pagination").html(paginate);    
                    }
                }); 
            // Generate Pagination
        }   
    })
    .fail(function(){
        $("#this_category_product_container").html('Query to sever unsuccessful. Try again shortly!');
    });

})(jQuery);
```

Would be pleased to get some help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured out the problem. Simply added

```
$config['cur_page'] = $page;
```

to the pagination config initialize and that passed the value of the current page to the Pagination class

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem may be that you didn't declare the page variable in ajax.

```
(function($){       

    var cat_id          = $("#filter_form_id input[name=cat_id]").val();
    // where is var page??
    var form_data = {
        cat_id : cat_id,
        page : page,
        secure_csrf_token_name : csrf
    }
    ...
```